# Groovy Class in Mule 4

Tags: spring-bean, mule4

I want to invoke a groovy class in Execute Component of Scripting Module.
Earlier I kept the groovy packages in src/main/resources folder. I was able to invoke them using

```
import com.exampes.project.service.CustomerService;
```

But when added Spring Module to Mule 4 (for adding spring beans), I get an error

```
com.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.exampes.project.service.CustomerService
@ line 1, column1.
  import com.exampes.project.service.CustomerService;
  ^
```

I tried adding the packages in mule-artifact.json too:

```
{
  "minMuleVersion": "4.3.0",
  "requiredProduct": "MULE_EE",
  "classLoaderModelLoaderDescriptor": {
     "id": "mule",
     "attributes": {
       "exportedResources": [ "jpa-beans.xml" ],
       "exportedPackages": [ "com.examples.project.service"]
      }
   }
}
```

Any Idea why this is happening?
I tried by keeping the packages in src/main/java, but didn't help. Do I need to change the packages location?

Comment: Do you use a groovy maven plugin?

Comment: @aled No, have not used it yet

Comment: Was it working before you added the Spring module?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project and added the Spring Module without any issues. I didn't had to change the mule-artifact.json. Current versions of the Mule Maven Plugin handle the packging much more automatically. What I noticed is that sometimes the Spring beans you use might interact badly with the application. If you comment the `<spring:config>` element, do you still have the same issue? It might point to the actual cause.